# Upload functionality using Robot class in selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, upload, webdriver

I am using the following code:code runs fine but instead of pasting the path of the file at upload window, it pastes the path on the TestNG console. Does not throw any error and on browser the window pop up remains blank.If someone has faced the same issue then please help me out in it

```
  StringSelection ss= new StringSelection("D:\\test.docx");
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss,null);

  Robot robot = new Robot();

  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Did you try the method whereby you use '.sendKeys()' on the 'input' element and then ',click()' on whatever is your submit element?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response.. I tried sendkeys but it didn't work.. I am testing a scenario in which I am trying to send a mail by attaching a file or document.using gmail for this... If you have some code using robot class for this then do share as that can be more helpful...Thanks

Comment: Gmail is purposefully difficult to automated via the UI. They provided an API in its place. Google really don't want it automated via Selenium/Webdriver as far as most of the community of automation folks understand. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Mark...well I tried the same code on a web page of an application too but still the same issue is there..app halts after opening the browse window..n no error on test ng console...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and sorted using this "little" trick.Everything is all fine only the trick here is that your control/mouse should be on the application under test.

A) If you run on Jenkins, it will work fine as when Jenkins execute the scripts on the Application under test. By default, focus of your control is on application itself.

B) If you run on Debug mode, sometimes focus moves to TestNg console/ Eclipse Script editor, that doesn't allow paste of the filepath to the Open/File Explorer Window. Just click on the application, before the eclipse execute the Robot code of file upload.
Please let me know if it works or not works.

Hard fact is that "Robot class" will not work with selenium on Jenkins as expected for "file upload".